# Can not run IOCipher Example Project

Tags: android, encryption, sqlcipher-android

I am trying to run IOCipher Example on https://github.com/guardianproject/IOCipherExample but I get force close when I run it. I cannot even run a single line vfs = VirtualFileSystem.get(); I installed it's library by write this line "compile 'info.guardianproject.iocipher:IOCipherStandalone:0.4'" in build.gradle(Module:app) file and build the project. 
I really don't know what is the problem. :(

Here is the logcat output:

```
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: futex_wait+0x112/0x250
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: do_futex+0xdc/0xb30
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: compat_SyS_futex+0x75/0x150
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: do_syscall_32_irqs_off+0x5f/0x180
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: entry_INT80_compat+0x36/0x50
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #00 pc 00013300  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+32)
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #01 pc 001018f7  [stack:3424] (???)
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   - waiting on <0x3c7f4d7e> (a java.lang.Daemons$GCDaemon)
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at java.lang.Daemons$GCDaemon.run(Daemons.java:344)
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   - locked <0x3c7f4d7e> (a java.lang.Daemons$GCDaemon)
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] 
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] "Binder_1" prio=5 tid=12 Native
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c5b0a0 self=0xeec5f400
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | sysTid=3425 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf3c54780
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | state=S schedstat=( 17494491 12575701 16 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=2 HZ=100
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | stack=0xe371d000-0xe371f000 stackSize=1012KB
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | held mutexes=
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: binder_thread_read+0x837/0xf00
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: binder_ioctl_write_read.isra.39+0xf2/0x260
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: binder_ioctl+0x219/0x5ea
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: compat_SyS_ioctl+0xc0/0x1130
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: do_syscall_32_irqs_off+0x5f/0x180
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: entry_INT80_compat+0x36/0x50
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #00 pc 00073e26  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+22)
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #01 pc 000adc5a  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+42)
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #02 pc 0002e26b  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+251)
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #03 pc 0002ec65  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+37)
07-23 00:57:36.389: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #04 pc 0002ed29  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+105)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #05 pc 000377a8  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+40)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #06 pc 000169de  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+398)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #07 pc 00071d92  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+98)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #08 pc 000160fa  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+122)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #09 pc 000211d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+56)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #10 pc 0001c559  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+25)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #11 pc 00013126  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   (no managed stack frames)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] 
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] "Binder_2" prio=5 tid=13 Native
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c5e0a0 self=0xf3c33400
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | sysTid=3426 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xeecae080
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | state=S schedstat=( 1862003 7561750 6 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | stack=0xe361f000-0xe3621000 stackSize=1012KB
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | held mutexes=
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: binder_thread_read+0x837/0xf00
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: binder_ioctl_write_read.isra.39+0xf2/0x260
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: binder_ioctl+0x219/0x5ea
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: compat_SyS_ioctl+0xc0/0x1130
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: do_syscall_32_irqs_off+0x5f/0x180
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: entry_INT80_compat+0x36/0x50
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #00 pc 00073e26  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+22)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #01 pc 000adc5a  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+42)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #02 pc 0002e26b  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+251)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #03 pc 0002ec65  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+37)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #04 pc 0002ed29  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+105)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #05 pc 000377a8  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+40)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #06 pc 000169de  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+398)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #07 pc 00071d92  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+98)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #08 pc 000160fa  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+122)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #09 pc 000211d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+56)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #10 pc 0001c559  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+25)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #11 pc 00013126  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   (no managed stack frames)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] 
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] "Thread-203" prio=5 tid=14 Native
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c05d60 self=0xf3c32800
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | sysTid=3431 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf3c54a00
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | state=S schedstat=( 2014843 244316 6 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | stack=0xe3239000-0xe323b000 stackSize=1036KB
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | held mutexes=
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: __skb_recv_datagram+0x51a/0x570
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: skb_recv_datagram+0x30/0x40
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: unix_accept+0x65/0x130
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: SYSC_accept4+0xeb/0x1e0
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: SyS_accept4+0xe/0x10
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: compat_SyS_socketcall+0x170/0x430
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: do_syscall_32_irqs_off+0x5f/0x180
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   kernel: entry_INT80_compat+0x36/0x50
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #00 pc 00074571  /system/lib/libc.so (__accept4+17)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #01 pc 00000b37  /system/lib/libnetd_client.so (???)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #02 pc 0001bf03  /system/lib/libc.so (accept4+51)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #03 pc 0001bec2  /system/lib/libc.so (accept+50)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #04 pc 000cc894  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #05 pc 0030cd9f  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_android_net_LocalSocketImpl_accept__Ljava_io_FileDescriptor_2Landroid_net_LocalSocketImpl_2+179)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.accept(Native method)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.accept(LocalSocketImpl.java:331)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at android.net.LocalServerSocket.accept(LocalServerSocket.java:90)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server$SocketServerThread.run(Server.java:157)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] 
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/art(3409): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] 
07-23 00:57:36.390: A/libc(3409): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3409 (ra.fileiocipher)
07-23 00:57:36.820: E/lowmemorykiller(223): Error opening /proc/3409/oom_score_adj; errno=2
07-23 00:57:36.835: E/WindowState(1070): getStack: Window{38f52c30 u0 Starting com.example.sara.fileiocipher} couldn't find taskId=49 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:9750 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedLoop:8789 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked:8731 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.executeAppTransition:4151 
07-23 00:57:36.835: E/WindowState(1070): getStack: Window{38f52c30 u0 Starting com.example.sara.fileiocipher} couldn't find taskId=49 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:782 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.updateSurfaceWindowCrop:1284 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.setSurfaceBoundariesLocked:1459 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:9838 
07-23 00:57:36.835: E/WindowState(1070): getStack: Window{38f52c30 u0 Starting com.example.sara.fileiocipher} couldn't find taskId=49 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:782 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1286 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.updateSurfaceWindowCrop:1294 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.setSurfaceBoundariesLocked:1459 
07-23 00:57:36.836: E/WindowState(1070): getStack: Window{38f52c30 u0 Starting com.example.sara.fileiocipher} couldn't find taskId=49 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:782 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayId:787 com.android.server.wm.InputMonitor.updateInputWindowsLw:294 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:10089 
07-23 00:57:36.836: E/WindowState(1070): getStack: Window{38f52c30 u0 Starting com.example.sara.fileiocipher} couldn't find taskId=49 Callers=com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.setTouchExcludeRegion:237 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.setFocusedStackFrame:3994 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:10165 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedLoop:8789 
07-23 00:57:36.838: E/WindowState(1070): getStack: Window{38f52c30 u0 Starting com.example.sara.fileiocipher} couldn't find taskId=49 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:782 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getWindowList:1354 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2774 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2675 
07-23 00:57:36.838: E/WindowState(1070): getStack: Window{38f52c30 u0 Starting com.example.sara.fileiocipher} couldn't find taskId=49 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:782 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2779 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2675 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2597
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: What does the logcat output indicate?

Comment: did you find any solution ?